# Как реализовать скорость игрока в зависимости от шкалы скорости?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, libgdx

Пишу игру, где нужно бежать персонажем, скорость увеличивается, когда кликаешь на экран, но если кликов слишком много, то скорость должна падать. Как это, собственно, реализовать?

Есть примитивный код, лучше его как-то подкорректировать или я вообще не в том направлении иду?

```
void addSpeed()
{
    acceleration += 10;
    // если кликов не больше 50 - увел. скорость, если больше - уменьшаем
    if (acceleration <= 50)
        speed-=acceleration;
    // объект движется налево, поэтому для увеличения скорости отнимаем
    else 
        //в цикле рендера каждый кадр уменьшаю скорость и ускорение
        speed += (acceleration - 50);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно, чтобы в случае, если игрок слишком часто кликает на экран, то ускорение вместо увеличения - начинает падать. Через 3 публичных поля(они с комментариями) можете настроить поведение, необходимое вам.
А также, при необходимости, измените типы полей с `int` на `float`.

```
// Шаг увеличения ускорения.
public int AccelerationIncrementValue = 10;
// Шаг уменьшения ускорения.
public int AccelerationDecreaseValue = 25;
// Максимальное значение ускорения.
public int MaxAcceleration = 500;

void PlayerClicked()
{
    acceleration += AccelerationIncrementValue;
    if (acceleration + AccelerationIncrementValue <= MaxAcceleration)
        acceleration += AccelerationIncrementValue;
    else 
        acceleration -= AccelerationDecreaseValue;

    speed += acceleration;
}
```